# Prolog - two lists

Tags: list, prolog

I have two lists, for example:

```
L1=[1,0,1,0,1,1]
L2=[2,3,4,2,1,1]
```

and I want to check something like this

```
if (L1[k]==0)
sum=L2(k)
```

Is there any way to do that using prolog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nth0(Ind, Lst, Elem) enables random access to the list elements under SWI-Prolog
```